# I don't find gzip-compress-transformer in my mule studio palette

Tags: mule-studio

I don't find gzip-compress-transformer in my mule studio palette.
May you advise please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

At least through mule 3.7.3 this transformer is not in the palette, but should be available for use by putting it directly into your xlm.  I have not tried 3.8 yet but would guess it still has not been added to the gui.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would you please tell me where to add gzip transformer?